# How to delete an entity including all children

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I would like to do a cascading delete on an entity in the datastore. By this I mean all children and indirect children will also be deleted. I initially assumed this would be default behavior but somehow it is not...

My thought was something like this:

```
ndb.delete_multi(ndb.Model.query(ancestor=key).iter(keys_only = True))
```

But the Model should be a wildcard, because the entity can be the parent of several classes...

I would also like to delete BlobKeyProperties when deleting an entity. For this I was thinking
about:

```
@classmethod
  def _post_delete_hook(cls, key, future):
  # inform someone they have lost a friend
```

which I should maybe use for cascading delete as well?

Answer (score 6):

For kindless ancestor queries create the query from the [query class](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queryclass#constructor)

```
ndb.delete_multi(ndb.Query(ancestor=key).iter(keys_only = True))
```

I wouldn't use the cascading delete for all child entities.  If you have a lot then it will be much slower (unless you want to run the delete in a task).

Comment: Thanks! It's for a backend of a CMS, so I think it will manage.

Orphans are of no use in my application, because they will never be shown...

Comment: Remember that this query "will retrieve the specified ancestor and all of its descendants". Be careful, if the intent is to delete *only* children.